# Avoid global variables when using a predefined number of parameters in a function

Tags: c

I'm programing a command shell as an assignment where I need to run a series of commands.
I implemented a couple of structs to make it easier to escalate (as the project is going to get bigger during the semester)

commands are defined with three values:
(tokens is an array of all the flags that are passed to the command and also the values for things like "mkdir dir")

```
struct cmd {
    char *cmd_name;
    int (*cmd_fun)(char *tokens[], int ntokens);
    char *cmd_help;
};
```

and then created as a struct of all of them

```
struct cmd cmds[] ={
    {"command1", command1, "description of command1"},
    {"command2", command2, "description of command2"},
    {NULL,  NULL, NULL}
};
```

So far this works great. I have a function that reads the user input and compares it with the cmd_name then executing the cmd_fun.
The issue here is that I have a couple of commands in this struct that need a list to function, more specifically I have a history of commands, and I can't add it as a parameter because cmd_fun is defined with only tokens[] and ntokens.
I first got around this with a global variable that creates the list, but I now want to separate things into different files and having the list in my commands.c seems messy, plus my professor complained a bit about the implementation.

Is there any way I could pass this list more elegantly?

Comment: Do all these "special" commands take that list as argument? Then you could extend all your commands to have that parameter (even those that ignore it). Alternatively you could try doing something with `varargs` though that also requires modifying all existing commands

Comment: I ended up going with adding the list as a parameter to all the functions, even the ones that don't need it. In this case I made an struct that includes the list so I can add other parameters in the future as well. Not exactly what I was looking for, but it does the job and it's way better than before

Answer (score 0):

I cannot guess the strange case in which you need to avoid using globals in a function and signal that fact by using a special list of parameters.  Why not just write two functions, and call one or the other when you need?

You are talking about different ways to implement the storage of an algorithm (which is something the compiler must know at compilation time) and you are planning to implement a single function in two different ways, based on the argument list you pass to it, that you will detect at runtime?

Why not to write two functions, one with globals and one argument list, and other without them, and a different interface, and call one or the other depending on your needs... you cannot call a function in different ways at runtime because you have to write the function call in different ways at compilation time, so the whole problem is static in nature and you cannot move it to a runtime decision.

The simplest way to take a decision at runtime to call an implementation of one algorithm or another is to use function pointers.... but in that case, the argument lists cannot be different, just the pointer is dynamically assigned and so, a different call is made because of the pointer contents at the time of the call.

```
void f1(int, int, int);
void f2(int, int, int);

void (*ptr)(int, int, int);

int main()
{
    if (something) {
        ptr = f1;
    } else {
        ptr = f2;
    }

    /* .... later, much later */

    ptr(34, 25, 18);  /* will call f1 or f2 depending on 'something' */
}
```